# Can I increase the number of threads Steam uses for in-home streaming?

Tags: steam, performance, steam-in-home-streaming

I have a gaming PC with an i7 3820. It has 4 cores and 2 threads per core, making it capable of handling 8 threads

When I stream a game (The Witcher 2 for example) using in-home streaming, I notice in the video streaming details that the encoder is using 4 threads. Is there any way I can increase the number of threads to 8? Does it make sense to increase the number of threads to 8 for a CPU like the i7 3820?

Comment: The way I understand it, as long as your PC is doing hardware encoding, increasing the number of *CPU* cores for streaming should yield no real benefit.

Comment: I don't think it's doing hardware encoding. It mentions using x264 and 4 threads, which is not a hardware encoder, AFAIK

Comment: I'd use "cores for streaming = number of cpu virtual cores - cores needed by game" as a rule of thumb. Otherwise game performance might take hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how:

In Steam, go to Steam menu -> Settings, then in the In-Home Streaming settings, press the "Advanced Host Options" button, and a window will appear. You can then select the number of threads used for software encoding.

This option wasn't there around the time I posted the question.. it seems like it was added recently.